# ImageView I can't display image

Tags: android, imageview

I've created very simple android application which display image.
Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/img_big_size"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Furthermore I have two the same pictures ,first img_big_size.jpg(size 468 KB) and  second img_small_size.jpg(size 192 KB).
The first image has a higher resolution so it takes more memory than second image.
When I try display second image(img_small_size.jpg) application works fine and display image.
But when I try display fist image(img_small_size.jpg) application don't display image only show black screen. Why my application can't display first image?? How display first image?

I want to display first image because when I zoom image first the picture  is more clear
than second image.

Link to images:
http://zapodaj.net/2096f7cc62055.jpg.html

http://zapodaj.net/cf7233054f2fc.jpg.html

Comment: where is textView1 in your xml?

Answer (score 4):

Your big image size dimen is : 1571x2166

**OpenGLRenderer** hardware Acceleration cannot handle bitmap larger than **2048x2048**. You can try to disable hardware Acceleration by defining **android:hardwareAccelerated="false**" inside  **in AndroidManifest.xml** file.

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true" >
```

or for your best performance, you can resize your image before displaying it.
reserving large heap will significantly decrease your app performance.

Comment: Does it cause  any bad consequences if I set android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ??

Comment: Yes, if you disable the feature, it will increase your app ram usage, and make your app resource consuming app !!! that's not good. also it's much better performance to use GPU to render your image.